# Namespace issues (.NET & WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces

Okay so I have encountered a frustrating issue with namespaces.

I am currently using

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Company.ecommerce.WPF"
```

And it seems to be able to get everything else fine from here apart from one class.

```
public class StringToVisibilityConverter
```

This class is inside >WPF>ProductFeatures>FeatureSet.XAML.CS and I am trying to use,

```
<local:StringToVisibilityConverter x:Key="StringToVis"/>
```

inside my FeatureSet.xaml

however no matter how I try and set the namespace it comes back with:

```
The tag 'StringToVisibilityConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-
namespace:Company.ecommerce.WPF'.
```

Comment: Try rebuilding your project. And try showing little bit more code. Especialy around said coverter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check namespace of you class

```
public class StringToVisibilityConverter
```

It should be same everywhere.

When we create a usercontrol in a folder, the namespace it gets created in is `parentnamespace.foldername`.

From the usercontrol UI and codebehind remove `.FolderName` and rebuild the project.It will work.

**OR**

Include the new namespace with `my` tag like

```
xmlns:my = ".......
```

and use it like

```
<my:StringToVisibilityConverter x:Key="StringToVis"/>
```

Comment: I have managed to fix my issue, this problem is solved! Thank you for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that ProductFeatures is another namespace, which would give

```
namespace Company.ecommerce.WPF.ProductFeatures
{
    public class StringToVisibilityConverter
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

If so, then I believe you need to reference it in XAML as `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Company.ecommerce.WPF.ProductFeatures"`